# How to update with Inner Join

Tags: c#, sql, workflow-foundation

How do I perform an Inner join as I want to retrieve information from another table called Medication with the attribute Description instead of Location description. How do I go about doing this?

```
 public static void UpdateLocationDescription( int locationID, string description, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction )
    {
        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        SqlCommand command;

        sqlString.Append( "UPDATE [Location] SET " );
        sqlString.Append( "description = @description " );
        sqlString.Append( "WHERE locationID = @locationID " );
        command = new SqlCommand( sqlString.ToString(), connection );
        if( ( transaction != null ) ) command.Transaction = transaction;

        command.Parameters.Add( "@locationID", SqlDbType.Int ).Value = locationID;
        command.Parameters.Add( "@description", SqlDbType.VarChar ).Value = description;


        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if( !( rowsAffected == 1 ) )
        {
            throw new Exception( "An error has occurred while updating UpdateMedicationDispenseStatus." );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably going to want a different query.  Update shouldn't return anything to you.

Comment: Do you want to do the update and then get the data? Or you want to update the description from the Medication table?

Comment: Are you looking at a UNION ? are the tables related?

Comment: @unlimit update Location ID and then retrieve using a different Retrieve method.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad Yes they are related. I need some way of connecting the data when updating

Comment: oh ok ... in that Ron's answer looks good

Answer (score 0):

Using the "FROM" keyword you can do that.

```
UPDATE [Medication]

SET [Medication].description = @description

FROM [Medication] INNER JOIN [Location] ON [Medication].LocationID = [Location].LocationID

WHERE ...
```

Ofcouse I don't know your structure or requirements. But you write it just as a INNER JOIN with a SELECT statement. You can write a SELECT statement with the fields that you want to consider. Then just replace the "SELECT [fields]" part with "UPDATE [tableyouwantochange] SET [field]=[value]

To retrieve data just use a new SELECT statement.

Answer (score -1):

Do u mean like this ?

```
UPDATE [Location]

SET [Location].description = (SELECT top 1* m.description FROM Medication m WHERE m.LocationID =@LocationId)

WHERE Location.ID =@LocationId
```